# CSV Playback with Node Red

Tags: node.js, node-red

Disclaimer - I am not a software guy so please bear with me while I learn.

I am looking to use node red as a parser/translator by taking data from a CSV file and sending out the rows of data at 1Hz.  Let's say 5-10 rows of data being read and published per second.

Eventually, I will publish that data to some Modbus registers but I'm not there yet.

I have scoured the web and tried several examples, however, as soon as I trigger the flow, Node.Red stops responding and I have to delete the source CSV,(so it can't run any more) and restart node.red in order to get it back up in running.

I have many of the [Big Nodes](https://www.npmjs.com/~jacques44) from this guy installed and have tried a variety of different methods but I just can't seem to get it.

If I can get a single column of data from a CSV file being sent out one row at a time, I think that would keep me busy for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **file node** that will read a file a line at a time, you can then feed this through the **csv node** to parse out the fields in the CSV into an object so you can work with it.

The **delay node** has a rate limiting function that can be used to limit the flow to processing 1 message per second to achieve the rate you want.

All the nodes I've mentioned should be in the core set that ships with Node-RED